# Unable to install WhatsApp Business API Client using docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, messaging, whatsapp

I want to implement "WhatsApp Business API Client" in my web application.
I want to send document from my web application to customer using "WhatsApp Business API Client".
I have flow the instruction from bellow link

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises/get-started
```

I have created both Facebook and WhatsApp business account. I have also created app in Facebook and verify my business through Facebook.
After that I have started to install "WhatsApp Business API Client" using docker.
I have flow bellow link to install docker

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/on-premises/get-started/installation/dev-single-instance#step-6--login-and-authenticate
```

1. I have created "biz" using command from terminal
2. set WhatsApp API version "2.31.5"
   3  Run "docker-compose up -d" from  terminal.
   But when I run the above command then face some error in terminal
   Error are given bellow

   C:\xampp\htdocs\whatapp>docker-compose up -d

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "docker\api\client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version

   File "docker\api\daemon.py", line 181, in version

   File "docker\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in inner

   File "docker\api\client.py", line 237, in _get

   File "requests\sessions.py", line 543, in get

   File "requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request

   File "requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send

   File "requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send

   File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen

   File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request

   File "http\client.py", line 1255, in request

   File "http\client.py", line 1301, in _send_request

   File "http\client.py", line 1250, in endheaders

   File "http\client.py", line 1010, in _send_output

   File "http\client.py", line 950, in send

   File "docker\transport\npipeconn.py", line 32, in connect

   File "docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 23, in wrapped

   File "docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 72, in connect

   File "docker\transport\npipesocket.py", line 52, in connect

   pywintypes.error: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "docker-compose", line 3, in

   File "compose\cli\main.py", line 81, in main

   File "compose\cli\main.py", line 200, in perform_command

   File "compose\cli\command.py", line 60, in project_from_options

   File "compose\cli\command.py", line 152, in get_project

   File "compose\cli\docker_client.py", line 41, in get_client

   File "compose\cli\docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client

   File "docker\api\client.py", line 197, in **init**

   File "docker\api\client.py", line 221, in
   _retrieve_server_version

   docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: (2, 'CreateFile', 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

   [6012] Failed to execute script docker-compose

Please help me how solve the issue.
Thank You

Comment: Please share your ``docker-compose`` and ``python`` program so we can help you.

Comment: Which information you want and how to share

Comment: Commands:
  build              Build or rebuild services

  config             Validate and view the Compose file

  create             Create services

  down               Stop and remove resources
  events             Receive real time events from containers
  exec               Execute a command in a running container
  help               Get help on a command
  pause              Pause services
  port               Print the public port for a port binding
  ps                 List containers

Docker Compose is now in the Docker CLI, try `docker compose`